# Is difference equation $t_n = (a+b) t_{n-1} - ab \cdot t_{n-2}$ possible ($t_1 = a + b$ and $t_2 = a^2 + ab + b^2$)?

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations

I had problem solving difference equation $t_n = (a+b) t_{n-1} - ab \cdot t_{n-2}$ where $t_1 = a + b$ and $t_2 = a^2 + ab + b^2$.

Here is what I have done:

First, I've written down the equation as $$t^2 = (a+b) t - ab$$

which is $$t^2 - (a+b) t + ab = 0$$

Now solving this quadratic equation we get
$$t_{1,2} = \frac{2(a + b) \pm \sqrt{(a+b)^2 - 4ab}}{2} = \frac{2(a+b)\pm (a - b)}{2}$$
$$t_1 = \frac{3a+b}{2}$$
$$t_2 = \frac{3b+a}{2}$$

So, that leads us to
$$t_n = C_1\cdot t_1^n + C_2 \cdot t_2^n = C_1\cdot (\frac{3a+b}{2})^n + C_2 \cdot (\frac{3b+a}{2})^n$$

and we have to find $C_1$ and $C_2$ now.

Putting $n = 1$ and $n = 2$ in last equation, keeping in mind that $t_1 = a + b$ and $t_2 = a^2 + ab + b^2$ we'll get system of 2 equations with 2 variables
$$a + b =  C_1\cdot \frac{3a+b}{2} + C_2 \cdot \frac{3b+a}{2}$$
$$a^2 + ab + b^2 =  C_1\cdot (\frac{3a+b}{2})^2 + C_2 \cdot (\frac{3b+a}{2})^2$$

What was confusing to me was that, if we have $a = 1$ and $b = 1$ the system is not possible.
So, my question is what is wrong here and how to finish this?

Comment: Note: $t^2 - (a+b)t + ab = (t - a)(t - b)$, so the roots are $t=a$ and $t=b$.

Comment: Also, once you fix your quadratic equation solution, you still need to deal with the case $a=b$ separately: if $a\ne b$, the solution is of the form $C_1a^n+C_2b^n$, but if $a=b$ the solution is of the form $C_1a^n+C_2na^n=(C_1+C_2n)a^n$

Comment: Alt. hint: write it as $\,t_n - a t_{n-1} = b \left( t_{n-1} - a t_{n-2} \right)\,$, so $\,u_n = t_n - at_{n-1} \,$ is a geometric progression.

Answer (score 1):

Solving by characteristics method:

$t^2-(a+b) t+ab=0$

Solution $t=a, b$

Case 1 : $a\neq b$

Then $t_n=c_1a^n+c_2b^n$ for $c_1, c_2$ constants.

$t_1=a+b$ implies $c_1 a+c_2b=a+b \space \space ......(1) $

$t_2=a^2+ab+b^2$ implies $c_1 a^2+c_2b^2=a^2+ab+b^2..... (2) $

$(2) -a×(1) $ implies $c_2=\frac{b}{b-a}$ and using $c_2$ in  $(1) $ , we get $c_1=\frac{q}{a-b}$

Hence solution : $t_n=\frac{a}{a-b}a^n+\frac{b}{b-a}b^n$

Case 2 : $a=b$

Then $t_n=(c_1+c_2n)a^n$

Solution : $t_n=(\frac{a^2+ab-b^2}{a^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}n)a^n$